# In Equivalence Partitioning, do I include the absence of condition in my partition, too?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Suppose I am writing a test method for an object.

This object replaces sequences of blank characters in a paragraph with just one single blank character.

I came up with this partition:

1. Sentences with 0 blank spaces
2. Sentences with only blank characters.
3. Sentences with blank characters in the beginning sentence.
4. Sentences with blank characters in the end of the sentence.

Do I also include 1?  I'm suspicious as 1 refers to the absence of blank space while others refer to the presence of blank space.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `Do I also include 1?` -- Of course.  Testing for proper behavior in the absence of something is just as valid and just as important as testing for proper behavior when it is present.  Incidentally, you're missing at least one test case.  Can you guess what it is?

Answer (score 2):

The fact case 1 *"refers to the absence of blank space while others refer to the presence of blank space"* just means it makes sense to **create an own partition for it** - and not to leave them out.

And as long as sentences with no blank spaces are allowed input data for the replace function of your object, you surely should test them.

Don't forget there are also sentences containing blank spaces, but neither at the beginning nor at the end. These sentences can be partitioned further, and you probably should do this.

Answer (score 1):

In general all tests should include at least:

- Positive Result **and**
- Negative Result

Where there is more than one positive or negative condition then you need to include each possible type of case.  Where **counts** are important this generally splits down to:

- 0 *often a special case*
- Less Than Some Value(s)
- Exactly Some Value(s)
- More Than Some Value(s)
- Between values *If more than one Significan Value*
- The biggest possible to represent value

Sometimes these condense e.g. if the significant count is 1 then 0 and less than are the same test.

Floating point numbers add:

- Exactly
- Almost/nearly
- PINF
- NINF
- NAN

Likewise, when position is significant your possible test you basic categories are:

- Beginning
- Before
- At
- In
- Between
- After
- End
- Nowhere
- Everywhere